# Привет всем. Не могу вывести время в форму для ввода текста. Подскажите в чем проблема. Делаю по методичке

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Clock</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function clock() // создание функции с именем clock()
    {
      var day = new Date(); // переменной day присваиваем встроенный объект date;
      var clock f = day.getHours() + ": " + day.getMinutes() + ": " + day.getSeconds(); //методы объекта date
      document.write(forma.f_clock.value = clock f); //вывод в input
      setTimeout("clock()", 100); //задаем интервал времени
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name="forma">
    <input name="f_clock" maxlength="8"></form>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Должно бы как-то так думаю

```js
function clock(){
  let day=new Date(); // переменной day присваиваем встроенный объект date;
  let clock =day.getHours()+": "+day.getMinutes()+": "+day.getSeconds(); //методы объекта date
  forma.f_clock.value=clock; //вывод в input
  
}

 setInterval(clock, 1000); //задаем интервал времени
```

```html
<form name= "forma">
  <input name="f_clock" maxlength="8">
</form>
```